# Young diagram for $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I am trying to draw the Young diagram for $S_5$. I know the following pieces of information about $S_5$.

1. The order of the group is $120$.
2. The number of conjugacy classes and so partitions is $7$.
3. Degrees of irreducible representations $1,1,4,4,5,5,6$.
4. The partition is $1 + 10 + 15 + 20 + 20 + 24 + 30 = 120$.

I understand that the Young diagram should contain $30$ boxes in the first row, $24$ boxes in the second row, $20$ boxes in the third and fourth rows, $15$ boxes in the fifth row, $10$ boxes in the sixth row and $1$ box in the seventh row.

So, the Young diagram is as follows.

My question:

Am I doing it right? I understand that the next step is to fill up the boxes to make it a Young tableau.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

I was able to compute the partition as follows.

[image]

What should be my next step?

**UPDATE 2:**

I think I was able to draw the Young diagrams.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here.  Each irreducible representation  of $S_5$ is associated with a partition and young diagram, but what is the "young diagram of $S_5$"?  Why do you need to make it into a young tableau?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  It might help if you state the problem.

Comment: @JairTaylor, this is not a homework problem. I am trying to compute all the irreps of $S_5$. I am done with trivial, parity, standard and product of sign and standard representations. To compute the rest three, I am going through Young Tableaux and the Representations
of the Symmetric Group by Jeremy Booher. It is suggested in that note that a more systematic approach  is to work out the Young diagram and Young tableaux first.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I think I am missing something here. Isn't the only partition of $120$ for irreps $1 + 10 + 15 + 20 + 20 + 24 + 30 = 120$?

Comment: A Young diagram for $S_5$ should correspond to a partition of 5, not 5!

Comment: Each irrep will correspond to a partition of 5.  So the $7$ associated partitions are $5$, $41$,$32$,$311$,$221$,$2111$,$11111$.  If you count the number of standard young tableaux for each of these shapes you will get the dimension of each irrep.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I think my understanding with partition was wrong. Now I have found two different partitions for the same cycle structure in two different sources. So, I am even more confused. I have posted a question about it here ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560504/confusing-partitions-of-s-5-in-two-different-sources ).

Comment: @JairTaylor, I think I am able to draw the Young diagrams. Could you please check if it is correctly done in UPDATE 2? Thanks.

Comment: Looks good.  If you want the dimensions of the irreps, you can list out all of the standard young tableaux of the given shape.

Comment: How did you know the degree of irreducible representations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although late in the party, I post an answer with images of two .pdf pages produced by $\LaTeX$ since MathJaX doesn't support the Young Tableaux package.

The symmetric group $\mathrm S_{5}$ has $5!\boldsymbol{=}120$ elements in 7 conjugacy classes. The corresponding partitions, Young Diagrams (YD), $\lambda$'s,  $\nu$'s and the cardinalities  $h_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}$ are shown in Table I :

---

**Table I**

[image]

---

<sup>Note that 
\begin{equation}
\!\!\!\!\sum\limits_{j\boldsymbol{=}1}^{j\boldsymbol{=}7}h_{j}\boldsymbol{=}h_{1}\boldsymbol{+}h_{2}\boldsymbol{+}h_{3}\boldsymbol{+}h_{4}\boldsymbol{+}h_{5}\boldsymbol{+}h_{6}\boldsymbol{+}h_{7}\boldsymbol{=}1\boldsymbol{+}10\boldsymbol{+}15\boldsymbol{+}20\boldsymbol{+}20\boldsymbol{+}30\boldsymbol{+}24\boldsymbol{=}120\boldsymbol{=}5!
\tag{01}\label{01}   
\end{equation}</sup>

---

The degrees $\,f_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}\,$ (dimensions)  of irreducible representations of the symmetric group $\mathrm S_{5}$ from the number of Standard Young Tableaux (SYT) per partition-conjugacy class using the hook length formula
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:f_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{n!}{\prod_{\imath\jmath}\mathrm{h}_{\imath\jmath}}\,,\quad \boldsymbol{\lambda}\boldsymbol{\vdash}n \vphantom{\dfrac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}}\:\:}   
\tag{02}\label{02}   
\end{equation}
are shown in Table II :

---

**Table II**

[image]

---

<sup>Note that 
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{j\boldsymbol{=}1}^{j\boldsymbol{=}7}f^2_{j}\boldsymbol{=}f^2_{1}\boldsymbol{+}f^2_{2}\boldsymbol{+}f^2_{3}\boldsymbol{+}f^2_{4}\boldsymbol{+}f^2_{5}\boldsymbol{+}f^2_{6}\boldsymbol{+}f^2_{7}\boldsymbol{=}1^2\boldsymbol{+}4^2\boldsymbol{+}5^2\boldsymbol{+}6^2\boldsymbol{+}5^2\boldsymbol{+}4^2\boldsymbol{+}1^2\boldsymbol{=}120\boldsymbol{=}5!
\tag{03}\label{03}   
\end{equation}</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I do not think your first attempt is right, but it seems your updates are much more succesful.  The partitions of $5$ are
$$
\{\{5\},\{4,1\},\{3,2\},\{3,1,1\},\{2,2,1\},\{2,1,1,1\},\{1,1,1,1,1\}\}
$$
so your Young diagram will have $5$ boxes.  If $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_p\}$ is one of the above partitions, then the corresponding Young diagram will have $\lambda_1$ boxes on row $1$,  $\lambda_2$ boxes on row $2$ and so forth, up to $\lambda_p$ boxes on row $p$, with $p\le 5$, in agreement with your second update.

One can use instead of Young diagrams so-called [Ferrers diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Ferrers_diagram), which are basically Young diagrams with boxes replaced by dots, and more amenable to MathJax than boxes.   Those would be (I don't have much control over the spacings forgive me)
$$
\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\, \qquad 
\stackrel{\Large\bullet\,\bullet\,\bullet\,\bullet}{\bullet\phantom{E\cdot \cdot\cdot}} 
\, ,\qquad 
\stackrel{\Large\bullet\,\bullet\,\bullet}{\bullet\bullet\phantom{\cdot}} \qquad 
\stackrel{\Large\bullet\bullet}{\stackrel{\Large\bullet\phantom{e}}{\bullet\phantom{e}}}
$$ 
etc.  for the partitions $\{5\}, \{4,1\}, \{3,2\} ,\{3,1,1\}$ respectively.  The character table is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 6 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 5 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 4 \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\, .
$$