# Confusing partitions of $S_5$ in two different sources

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I am trying to understand the partitions of $S_5$ created by it's conjugacy classes but two sources have two different partitions.

**[Source 1](http://webhome.weizmann.ac.il/home/fnkirson/Alg13/Young_diagrams.pdf)**:
[image]

**[Source 2:](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S5#Interpretation_as_symmetric_group)**
[image]

So, for example, in the first table, the partition for cycle structure ()()()()() i.e. $5$ $1$-cycle is $5+0+0+0+0$ but in the second table it is $1+1+1+1+1$.

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Normally partition of an integer composed of only positive whole numbers , we generally don't allow zero as a part of the partition, the first table seems to have errors. Second table is fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two sources differ by *conjugating* the partition, i.e., reading the boxes in the Young diagram horizontally vs reading them vertically.  Thus 4+1 in the first source corresponds to 2+1+1+1 in the second, and vica versa.  It is just a difference in notation between the two sources.